# How to integrate osgi-blueprint and apache camel, Any sample code?

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am setting  osgi-bluprint and apache camle project and I am wondering how we can integrate this two compoenent.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples out of the box with Apache Camel.

See the OSGi / blueprint examples at:

- https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/camel-2.x/examples#welcome-to-the-apache-camel-examples

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good place to start.

- http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html

It is a very common pattern to use OSGi-blueprint and Camel (with OSGi runtimes such as Apache Karaf) and there are plenty of examples out there.